# How can I stop a function from running when I want to start a second one?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I created a function to go through an array to load some products on my website, then I created an element.eventListener to run another different array. I don't want the first function to keep going and keep loading products from the first array. I only want the eventListener to work when clicking a button.

This is what I am trying:

```
function cargadorProductos(productos) {
    
    contenedorProductos.innerHTML="";

    productos.forEach(producto => {
        let div = document.createElement('div');
        div.classList.add ("producto");
        div.innerHTML = `
        <img  class="foto"  src="${producto.img}" alt="cara"> 
    <div class="descripcion"> <h3> Brocha difuminadora </h3> </div>
    <div class="precio"> <h3>${producto.precio}</h3> </div>
    <button class="boton" type= "button" id= "${producto.id}"> Comprar! </button> 
        `

        contenedorProductos.append(div); 
    });

}

cargadorProductos(productos); 
 ** // this is first function, all good till here. but then I want to stop this and run below.     **



  botonCara.addEventListener('click',  () => { 
       

    cara.forEach(cara => {
        let div = document.createElement('div');
        div.classList.add ("producto");
        div.innerHTML = `
        <img  class="foto"  src="${cara.img}" alt="cara"> 
    <div class="descripcion"> <h3> Brocha difuminadora </h3> </div>
    <div class="precio"> <h3>${cara.precio}</h3> </div>
    <button class="boton" type= "button" id= "${cara.id}"> Comprar! </button> 
        `

        contenedorProductos.append(div); 
       
    });    **//this works just fine, just want to stop  cargadorProductos(productos);   **
```

Comment: You cannot stop a function on a button click. Why do you even need this? How long does the first function take to run?

Comment: @tkausl he can control with a ``for`` loop and an extra variable but I don't see the practicality because he won't have the chance to trigger a stop before it runs till the end.

Comment: Maybe render a part of the array instead `productos.slice(0, 100)`

Comment: @tkausl that's the anwer, namely "no you can't". Please write it up as an answer, with reference to JavaScript being single threaded and a fuller explanation as  you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to achieve this with a for loop. You need to be able to run the functions in parallel. One way to do this would be to use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) or [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout)

Here is a sample implementation:

The idea here is that the function inside the `setinterval` will keep running unless interrupted by the function at the click of a button. When the button clicks, it shall clear the current running timer & hence the loop.

```js
// Dummy data & Variables
var productos = [{img: "", precio: "One", id: 1}, {img: "", precio: "Two", id: 2}, {img: "", precio: "Three", id: 3 }]
var cara = [{img: "", precio: "NewOne", id: 1}, {img: "", precio: "NewTwo", id: 2}, {img: "", precio: "NewThree", id: 3 }]

var contenedorProductos = document.getElementById("contenedorProductos");
var botonCara = document.getElementById("botonCara");

// Variables to control the load
var currentIndex = 0, interval = 1000, timer = 0;

function cargadorProductos(productos) {
  contenedorProductos.innerHTML = "";
  timer = setInterval(() => {
    let producto = productos[currentIndex++];
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.classList.add("producto");
    div.innerHTML = `<img  class="foto"  src="${producto.img}" alt="cara"> 
    <div class="descripcion"> <h3> Brocha difuminadora </h3> </div>
    <div class="precio"> <h3>${producto.precio}</h3> </div>
    <button class="boton" type= "button" id= "${producto.id}"> Comprar! </button>`
    contenedorProductos.append(div);

    if (currentIndex == productos.length) clearInterval(timer);
  }, interval);
}

cargadorProductos(productos);

botonCara.addEventListener('click', () => {
  clearInterval(timer);
  cara.forEach(cara => {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.classList.add("producto");
    div.innerHTML = `<img  class="foto"  src="${cara.img}" alt="cara"> 
    <div class="descripcion"> <h3> Brocha difuminadora </h3> </div>
    <div class="precio"> <h3>${cara.precio}</h3> </div>
    <button class="boton" type= "button" id= "${cara.id}"> Comprar! </button>`
    contenedorProductos.append(div);
  });
});
```

```html
<button id="botonCara">botonCara</button>
<div id="contenedorProductos"></div>
```